# Find $\int \frac{1}{\tan x-\sin x}\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> 1. $$\int \frac{1}{\tan x-\sin x}\,dx$$

Boy, where do I even begin? I mean, what the heck is this?

Comment: The answer to your questions: You begin by writing $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and to the second one, an integration problem.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hmm, too bad that's the first problem, looking at the "1." at the beginning. That doesn't bode well for the remainder.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\int \frac{1}{\tan x-\sin x}\ dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x(1-\cos x)}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{1-(1-\cos x)}{\sin x(1-\cos x)}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{1}{\sin x(1-\cos x)}\ dx-\int\frac{1}{\sin x}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\sin x} {(1-\cos^2x)(1-\cos x)}\ dx-\int\csc x\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\sin x} {(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)^2}\ dx-\ln|\csc x-\cot x|+C$$
let $\cos x=t\implies -\sin x dx=dt$, 
$$=-\int \frac{dt} {(1+t)(1-t)^2}-\ln|\csc x-\cot x|+C$$
$$=-\frac 14\int\left( \frac{1} {1+t}+\frac{1} {1-t}+ \frac{2} {(1-t)^2}\right)\ dt-\ln|\csc x-\cot x|+C$$
I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Couldn't you have multiplied by the nr and dr by $\sin x$ in $\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x(1-\ cos x)}$ and then put $\cos x =t$?

Answer (score 2):

Just using the Pythagorean and rational identities we have: $$\int \frac{1}{\tan x - \sin x} dx = \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)\sin(x)} dx = \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}dx = \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)} dx + \int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^3(x)} dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)} dx + \int \frac{1-\sin^2(x)}{\sin^3(x)} dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)}dx + \int \frac{1}{\sin^3(x)} dx - \int \frac{1}{\sin(x)} dx$$
$$= \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)} dx + \int \csc^3(x) dx - \int \csc(x) dx.$$

Now the first integral can be solved by $u$-substitution. The last two are standard examples in Calculus 2. Either use a lookup table or refer to your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Apply universal trigonometric substitution
$$t=\tan\dfrac x2,\quad dx = \dfrac{2dt}{1+t^2},\quad \sin x = \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2},\quad \tan x = \dfrac{2t}{1-t^2},$$
then
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{\tan x - \sin x} = \int\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}-\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}\dfrac{2dt}{1+t^2} = \int\dfrac{1-t^2}{2t^3}dt = \dfrac12\left(\dfrac{t^{-2}}{-2}- \log t\right)+const.$$